# c3.js reduce width of x-axis

Tags: c3.js

is there a way to reduce the width of x-axis (see picture) in c3? Even if I tried to set "stroke-width" attribute to the "<"path">" tag with different values - it didn't make any visual changes. Thank you for your advices in advance. 
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqMra.jpg)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#' + chartId,
        data: {
            columns: columns,
            type: 'bar',
            labels: true
        },
        interaction: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            show: false
        },
        color: {
            pattern: colorPattern
        },
        bar: {
            width: { ratio: 0.7 },
            space: 0.25
        },
        size: settings.ChartSizes.BarChart,
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            grouped: true,
            item: {
                onclick: function (d) {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter === 1) {
                        chart.hide();
                        chart.show(d);
                    } else {
                        chart.show();
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: categories,
                show: showAxe
            },
            y: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue, caused by you not picking up the c3.css file - see https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1962

If you can fix that, the problem goes away